# Has a reason ever been given for the decision to use the name Martha?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, inspiration

Superman and Batman mother’s both have the same name, has any writer of these comics ever discussed the reason for this or is it just chance?

Comment: [Same question on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77856/63559), where it's answered. As noted there though, both original authors being dead, it'll be hard getting more info in the matter

Answer (score 3):

There's several possible reasons

1. Martha was a [very popular name for girls and women at the time](https://nameberry.com/babyname/Martha#popularity)
   [image: Martha popularity]
2. The characters needed to be generic (so as not to upstage their famous sons), yet relatable. Picking a common woman's name made these women likely remind readers of their own mothers, or women they knew.
3. Martha was considered a patriotic name due to the [first First-Lady of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Washington) (remember, both launched around the time World War II was starting). Superman at the time was [fairly patriotic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7XZV.jpg) (and that was before he was [all in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2l4bz1FT8U)). Batman has never been terribly patriotic ([modern works notwithstanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5ltXldtwHo)), but with [other emerging comics waving the flag proudly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America), this would have been an easy way to make sure people knew Batman wasn't raised by (or would promulgate the ideas of) one of [those people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism).